# Send fixed amount on contract deployment

Tags: contract-deployment, address.transfer

I managed finally to get an erc20 contract working and creating an MCN (MyToken in this example) but can't figure out how to send a fixed amount of the MCN to multiple addresses on the contract deployment.
Ex:

On first deployment of the contract

- send 500 MCN to address 0x11111111111111111111111111
- send 500 MCN to address 0x22222222222222222222222222
- substract 1000 from balance.

here is my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.10;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) revert();
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract ForeignToken {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool);
}

contract Mycoin is owned {
    address owner = msg.sender;

    bool public purchasingAllowed = true;

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    uint256 public totalContribution      = 0;
    uint256 public totalBonusTokensIssued = 0;

    uint256 public totalSupply = 500000000000; // 5 billion coins

    function name()     constant returns (string) { return "Mycoin"; }
    function symbol()   constant returns (string) { return "MCN"; }
    function decimals() constant returns (uint8)  { return 18; }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        // mitigates the ERC20 short address attack
        if (msg.data.length < (2 * 32) + 4) revert();

        if (_to == 0x0) revert();

        if (_value == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        uint256 fromBalance = balances[msg.sender];

        bool sufficientFunds = fromBalance >= _value;
        bool overflowed      = balances[_to] + _value < balances[_to];

        if (sufficientFunds && !overflowed) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;

            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        // mitigates the ERC20 short address attack
        if (msg.data.length < (3 * 32) + 4) revert();

        if (_to == 0x0) revert();

        if (_value == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        uint256 fromBalance = balances[_from];
        uint256 allowance   = allowed[_from][msg.sender];

        bool sufficientFunds     = fromBalance <= _value;
        bool sufficientAllowance = allowance   <= _value;
        bool overflowed          = balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to];

        if (sufficientFunds && sufficientAllowance && !overflowed) {
            balances[_to]   += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;

            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        // mitigates the ERC20 spend/approval race condition
        if (_value != 0 && allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    function enablePurchasing() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) revert();

        purchasingAllowed = true;
    }

    function disablePurchasing() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) revert();

        purchasingAllowed = false;
    }

    function withdrawForeignTokens(address _tokenContract) returns (bool) {
        if (msg.sender != owner) revert();

        ForeignToken token = ForeignToken(_tokenContract);

        uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        return token.transfer(owner, amount);
    }

    function getStats() constant returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, bool) {
        return (totalContribution, totalSupply, totalBonusTokensIssued, purchasingAllowed);
    }

    function() payable {
        if (!purchasingAllowed) revert();

        if (msg.value == 0) return;

        owner.transfer(msg.value);
        totalContribution += tokensIssued;

        uint256 tokensIssued = (msg.value);

        totalSupply          += tokensIssued;
        balances[msg.sender] += tokensIssued;

        Transfer(address(this), msg.sender, tokensIssued);
    }

    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply       += mintedAmount;

        Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a constructor in which the balances are adjusted. Something like (untested):

```
function MyCoin() {
  balances[owner] = totalSupply - 1000;  // check totalSupply > 1000!
  balances[0x11111111111111111111111111] = 500;
  balances[0x22222222222222222222222222] = 500; 
}
```

Note that it's usual to assign the `totalSupply` to the deployer of the contract - they have to be assigned to someone otherwise they can never be moved in future.

Answer (score 1):

First, every contract (except abstractions) needs a constructor function. It has the same name as the contract. In it you can do things when the contract is deployed, for example set values to vars or use functions.

```
function Mycoin {
       transfer(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments:

- I'd suggest to drop the short address attack mitigation, even OpenZeppelin removed the mitigation from their contracts https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/261.
- You declare `function decimals() constant returns (uint8)  { return 18; }` and `uint256 public totalSupply = 500000000000; // 5 billion coins`. With 18 decimals the total supply should be `5000000000 * 10**18`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.
I'm still confused though as to the exponentiation using **
Are you suggesting me to write:
public totalSupply = 500000000000 * 10**18 ?

Comment: If you put `totalSupply = 5000000000` you are allocating `5000000000 / 10**18 = 0.000000005` tokens.

Comment: Why does the EtehreumWallet show the correct number though ? http://imgur.com/a/3ulDt

Comment: EthereumWallet is not aware of the decimals or tokens, it just shows the value of the state variable.

Comment: I see. So for 5 billions, the correct number is : 
uint256 public totalSupply = 500000000000000000000000000000; // 5 billion coins